# Como remover as figuras duplicadas geradas pela função geom_errorbar?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como faço para remover as outras marcações gerada pela função `geom_errorbar()`?

Necessito somente da marcação que está circulada na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Base de Dados**

```
dataset = structure(list(structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "BLOCO X", class = "factor"), 
    c(0L, 6L, 11L, 20L, 32L, 35L, 38L, 42L, 84L, 89L, 106L, 112L, 
    118L, 122L, 124L, 126L, 129L, 133L, 155L, 161L), c(6L, 11L, 
    20L, 32L, 35L, 38L, 42L, 84L, 89L, 106L, 112L, 118L, 122L, 
    124L, 126L, 129L, 133L, 155L, 161L, 203L), structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("COR 1", "COR 2", "COR 3", "COR 4"
    ), class = "factor"), c(26265L, 215L, 0L, 215L, 0L, 215L, 
    0L, 215L, 0L, 4737279L, 0L, 215L, 0L, 4737279L, 0L, 215L, 
    0L, 215L, 0L, 4737279L), c(153L, 215L, 0L, 215L, 0L, 215L, 
    0L, 215L, 0L, 255L, 0L, 215L, 0L, 255L, 0L, 215L, 0L, 215L, 
    0L, 255L), c(102L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 72L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 72L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 72L), c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 72L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 72L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 72L), c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
    25L, 25L, 25L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L), c(20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), c("#996600", "#D70000", 
    "#000000", "#D70000", "#000000", "#D70000", "#000000", "#D70000", 
    "#000000", "#FF4848", "#000000", "#D70000", "#000000", "#FF4848", 
    "#000000", "#D70000", "#000000", "#D70000", "#000000", "#FF4848"
    ), c("#996600", "#D70000", "#000000", "#D70000", "#000000", 
    "#D70000", "#000000", "#D70000", "#000000", "#FF4848", "#000000", 
    "#D70000", "#000000", "#FF4848", "#000000", "#D70000", "#000000", 
    "#D70000", "#000000", "#FF4848")), .Names = c("ID", "GEOLFROM", 
"GEOLTO", "LIT_01", "BACKCOLOR", "R", "G", "B", "ymin", "ymax", 
NA, "HEX_COLOR"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Gráfico**

```
library("ggplot2")

fun <- function(ref, cor){
  cor <- as.character(cor)
  x <- unique(ref)
  i <- match(x, ref)
  setNames(cor[i], ref[i])
}

dataset$LIT_01 = factor(as.character(dataset$LIT_01))
dataset$HEX_COLOR = rgb(dataset$R, dataset$G, dataset$B, maxColorValue = 255)

color_ref = with(dataset, fun(LIT_01, HEX_COLOR))

p = ggplot(dataset, aes(ID, (GEOLTO + GEOLFROM)/2, fill=LIT_01)) +
    geom_tile(aes(height = (GEOLTO - GEOLFROM), width = 0.2), colour="black", size=0.1) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin , ymax = ymax), width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(1.1)) +
    theme_classic() +
    labs(x = "ID", y = "METERS") +
    labs(fill = "LITHO")  +
    scale_fill_manual (values = color_ref, breaks = unique(dataset$LIT_01)) +
    scale_y_reverse() 
    
p
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como `geom_errorbar` nesse caso não está medindo, de fato, uma variabilidade, eu recomendo utilizar `geom_segment` para fazer a marcação desejada. No caso, são 3 segmentos construídos:

1. O segmento vertical de cada marcação;
2. Os dois segmentos horizontais de cada marcação.

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(ID, (GEOLTO + GEOLFROM)/2, fill=LIT_01)) +
  geom_tile(aes(height = (GEOLTO - GEOLFROM), width = 0.2), colour="black", size=0.1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.15, y = ymin, xend = 1.15, yend = ymax), size = 0.3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.1, y = ymin, xend = 1.2, yend = ymin), size = 0.3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.1, y = ymax, xend = 1.2, yend = ymax), size = 0.3) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "ID", y = "METERS") +
  labs(fill = "LITHO")  +
  scale_fill_manual (values = color_ref, breaks = unique(dataset$LIT_01)) +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]